# How to build android adb from source for a different host

Tags: c++, makefile, android-source

I have download the android sourc code and can build the adb for x86 using the command make adb. However, I want to use a different compiler to build adb and not use the default one which android uses for the host architecture. I am unable to find where the compiler for building host tools like ADB is configured in the android make file. Could someone help me out?

Comment: android comes with its own compiler, should be somewhere in prebuilt, you may find it using a find in the source tree

Comment: @OznOg I am trying to replace the path which prebuilt is pointed to by but I cant fin where the path is set.